# How to read data frame name from a csv and use it in a loop in R

Tags: r, csv

I  have created some 500 data frames in the global environment of R studio and I have the list of all these data frame names in a csv file. I need to collect the no. of observations of each data frames. I know I need to use the nrow(dataset_name) command but is there any way, I can create a loop such that R reads the dataset names from the csv and executes the nrow command?

p.s.- I am a newbie to R, so plz pardon me if this question is very basic.
TIA!

Regards,
Brock

Comment: you can do something like this: `sapply(readLines("dfnames.csv"), function(x) nrow(get(x)), USE.NAMES=TRUE)` ... but why do you want to save the names in a file and read those dfs in an indirect way? why dont you store all the dfs in a list in the program?

Comment: @chinsoon12 Thanks a lot! It`s a very good idea, how do I store all the dfs in a list?

Comment: to get the documentation, type this at the console: `?"[["` ... in general, you do something like `listDF[[stringDFname]] <- DF`

Comment: ok got it! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample Example Below:

```
 # Creating 3 data frames
 df1=data.frame(a=1:12,b=1:12)   # Number of rows 12
 df2=data.frame(a=1:5,b=1:5)     # Number of rows 5
 df3=data.frame(a=1:20,b=1:20)   # Number of rows 20

 # Storing the created data frames in a list
 df_names=list(df1,df2,df3)

 # Computing the number of rows for each data frame
 for(i in 1:length(df_names)){
 print(nrow(df_names[[i]]))
 }
 # [1] 12
 # [1] 5
 # [1] 20
```

Note that here the data frames created are all saved in a list, not the dataframe names but the data frames and not in the csv file.

If you have 500 dataframes with you with data frames name as df1,df2,....,df499, df500, you can create list using `paste` and then you can apply the same above for loop.

```
df_names=list(paste("df",1:500,sep=""))
```